# A phrase for witnessing something that happens every day

Tags: phrase-request, present-continuous, register

One wrote:

> **We can see** that many devices are being produced every day.

The aim of this sentence is to address something that regularly happens these days, but I am looking for more formal and idiomatic ways to say such a sentence

Maybe:

> Nowadays, we are observing the production of new devices on daily basis ..

What is the pattern to witness something currently happens around us...
Do we usually use present continues tense for these sentences like:

> These days, we are seeing an increasing amount of violence on television, and this is having a negative impact on children’s behaviour.

Comment: A simple version:   "*Every day*, devices are being produced in large numbers."  When "Every day" or "Every day now" begins the sentence like that, it can serve as the rhetorical gesture you're looking for.

Comment: @TRomano then in English it is not idiomatic to say "We are observing that phenomena "?

Comment: Those exact words?

Comment: @TRomano No!, *Every day* is a good point, but in Persian we sometimes use ourselves or the reader to witness it.... I mean is there such phrases in English too? if yes, what are those? I found in google "These days, we are seeing..." is common...

Comment: There are many such phrases for engaging an audience. They are essentially rhetorical gestures which offer varying degrees of flatulence.

Comment: @TRomano good! the tense also was important to me, for example "We are seeing" and not "we see" or "we can see" as it is in the original sentence.

Comment: Present and present-continuous are both possible, and the modal **can** also is permissible. We see...we are seeing....we can see. But "these days" is hardly "formal".   Formal writing that truly wishes to avoid a folksy tone would avoid phrases such as "these days" and "nowadays" and "all around us".

Answer (score 1):

All of these can describe what you mean.

> *Every day* we see something happen.
>
> We can observe that something happens *on a daily basis*.
>
> *Day after day* we see that something happens (recurring action)
>
> *Day by day* we see that something is happening (continuing action).

It is acceptable to say "We are seeing" instead of the simple "We see/observe", but it's sometimes considered poor writing style to use the present continuous tense when the simple present works.

It is also considered unnecessary to include the first-person (*I* or *we*) in expository writing. You are the one writing, so the reader assumes that it is your observation, or your opinion.

> Every day new devices of this type are produced.
>
> Companies come out with new devices of this type on a daily basis.

Of course, you will see many people use the first-person anyway, especially in less formal writing, so it's possible this style rule is falling out of fashion.

Comment: Thank you but It's not about "something happen". It's more stylistic pattern like *These days, we are seeing an increasing amount of violence on television, and this is having a negative impact on children’s behaviour.*

Comment: Yes, the same pattern is applicable.  "Every day we see more and more violence on television, which ..."  or simply "Every day there is more and more ..."

Comment: *These days* is in the register of casual conversation.